# Why does `bundle update rack` vendor millions of lines of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

For a security patch, I needed to update the rack gem, so I ran this:

`bundle update rack`

It took a while, and at the end I see this new folder `/vendor/cache/ruby/2.4.0/` and it contains 2.7 million lines of code.

This really doesn't seem right. Does anyone know what's happening? I tried to delete that folder, but when I ran `rails console` after that a message said I needed to run `bundle install`, which put all the contents back in that mammoth folder.

Comment: What's the output of `bundle env` and/or `cat .bundle/config`? I suspect that you've vendor'd your gems.

Comment: .bundle/config is `BUNDLE_CACHE_ALL: "true"` 
`BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/cache"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you've ran `bundle install --path=vendor/cache`. This vendors everything into `vendor/cache` as implied.

To reverse this, you can simply delete the line from the `.bundle/config` file, and delete the `vendor/cache` folder. Re-run `bundle update rack` and everything should be cleaned up nicely.